# Fresh installation on the same server where another core version was installed gives error

Tags: 7

I have my own remote server to play around. I gave Drupal 8 a go but decided today to delete it from my server and install Drupal 7.56 again.

So I deleted all files via FTP and deleted all tables in phpMyAdmin, uploaded the Drupal 7.56 files from a fresh package I downloaded from drupal.org but ran into this issue:

When running through the process of install.php I suddenly get these 2 error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: app_root in include_once() (line 690 of /var/www/clients/client1/web3/web/sites/default/settings.php).
Notice: Undefined variable: site_path in include_once() (line 690 of /var/www/clients/client1/web3/web/sites/default/settings.php).
```

So, after some Googling I found out it might have to do with the setting.php file of Drupal 8. The thing I don't understand is how this fresh install can search for the settings.php file of the Drupal 8 installation whilst I deleted every single file and table?

I checked my settings.php file of the Drupal 7 installation and there are only 648 lines, so I have no idea where to go searching...

Comment: Is your server using any kind of code caching? For servers with PHP FPM and Opcache/APC, you may have to restart the PHP FPM pools.

Comment: I just gave it a new try today after letting it rest for 12 hours. Everything installed fine with no errors so it must have to do something with some code caching but no idea what exactly..

Answer (score 1):

After you install Drupal, automatically Drupal set `sites/default` to `555` and `settings/default/settings.php` to `444` , *So* it means they haven't deleted .

my suggestion is to change the permission for them, them delete `settings.php` (**and make sure you delete it correctly** ), and when you got insure of deleting everything Setup Drupal 7.56 again.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So, I've changed permissions on sites/default to 777 and all its contents. Deleted all the files again (I am sure sites/default and settings.php within it has been deleted) and deleted all the tables in the MySQL database again. During the install process, on the "Install Profile" item (when the progress bar comes up) the 2 errors showed up again. Everything is installed as it should be in the database, but when I want to visit my website, I get a 404 error.

Comment: @Apoch8000 would you please drop the database and try to install everything again?

Comment: Ok, did what you asked and now I'm even more confused! I created a complete new database, deleted everything via FTP and re-uploaded a fresh package. In the install procedure, after filling in the new database credentials, I get the error that Drupal is already installed (!). There even is nothing in the new database ... Could it be something cache-wise from the server side?

Comment: @Apoch8000 No , it's not cache, it seems the database is not empty. please check everything carefully.

Comment: The database is a completely new one with a new user. There never has been something in that database so far...